# How change a element of fragment.xml from MainActivity.java

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want change an element of a fragment from MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);// => this is the error
...

list.setOnItemClickListener(new Adapter.OnItemClickListener() {//this can't work because list isn't in layout=>activity_main
....
```

I need manipulate 'lis't from MainActivity, but i can't, because the element "list" is in the fragment container.xml and isn't in activity_main.xml .
I can't move 'list' in activity_main.xml, because i need load into container.xml.
How can i call from MainActivity in the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why you need to perform action on fragments view in activity?**

You can do all this inside your fragment.

1. Add that fragment to activity.
2. In fragments onCreateView method get the view and do whatever you want.

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
   ListView list = (ListView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.list);// => this is the error

   list.setOnItemClickListener(new Adapter.OnItemClickListener() {});

   return inflatedView;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is a bad idea and it is better that you find a better solution for your requirement, the answer is that you can make your ListView inside fragment public static, and then perform your action on it like:

```
YourFragment.list.setOnItemClickListener(new Adapter.OnItemClickListener()...
```